# How do I make textarea's new line selectable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I wonder how can I achieve the same selectable new line as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsjEK.png) for `<textarea/>`.

and this is what the normal textarea looks like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltZV0.png).

I'm currently using react and I tried researching for answer everywhere but I can't find any solution that will work or relavant to the result I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks all

Comment: turns out it was the way Gecko and Blink render things differently, it looks as expected on Blink (chromium)

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet add:

```
textarea {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

This allows new lines to be selected as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, you can use  tag in html and add the below code to css file.

```
textarea {
white-space: pre;
```

}